# Why is the Horizontal Tension same here?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, string

Our sir told us that the horizontal tension will be equal throughout the string but why

[image: e]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only horizontal forces on the chain are at the end points and they must be equal.  The weight of the chain induces only vertical forces. Since there are no additional horizontal forces along the length of the chain, the horizontal tension must be constant.

Comment: string is having mass the tension will be different  at each point in the string bro

Comment: Total tension yes, but the mass with gravity only produces vertical forces.  You are asking about the horizontal component of tension, and it is constant.